# Why do some internal organs regenerate?

Tags: cell-biology, anatomy

I have been reading about the human liver and zebra fish heart muscle having the ability to regenerate. It seems to me that these organs have very little chance to become damaged or worn out. At the very least their chances of being damaged are comparable to other internal organs. So why those particular organs have the regenerative capability?

Comment: It makes perfect sense for the liver as this is the organ which carries the biggest load in terms of metabolism. The liver is also very important to metabolize a lot of substances that we take up (think of the Cytochrome P450 system). So it is a good idea for this organ to be able to regenerate.

Comment: I am unsure of what exactly you are asking. Is your question "Why does the liver regenerate but not other organs?" or "What important organs have the capacity to regenerate?"

Comment: @Chris - it doesn't make perfect sense to me on that basis. That argument can be made for any organ: "it's function is vital, therefore it makes sense that it has regenerative capability."

Comment: see @Chris, liver perform many vital tasks but those tasks wont cause it to physically worn out. Or do they? I am not sure.

Comment: @anongoodnurse why not what.

Comment: @anongoodnurse The liver plays a central role in removing toxins. So it can get exposed to a too high dose and suffer damage. See alcoholism for example. You can treat your liver very bad for years and it will still work somehow.

Comment: The liver's position in the circulatory system means that it's the first organ hit by toxins absorbed by the intestines (except maybe the intestines themselves). Detoxification of these compounds can involve generation of reactive oxygen species that damage DNA or protein. It doesn't even need to be chronic damage, excessive acetominophen with a little alcohol can destroy a liver pretty quickly. [carbon tetrachloride](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_tetrachloride#Safety) or [galactosamine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galactosamine) are used to induce liver failure in lab animals.

Comment: Chris and user137 makes sense :) similar things should be true for other animals too I guess. Great guys :) thanks

Comment: @Chris and user137: could you make an answer out of your comments? It is all based on obvious knowledge so don't bother with too much cites. Just to prevent deletion - I like the question as it has crossed my mind often!

Comment: @PankajPhartiyal I made some edits to the question to try and make the grammar and wording more easily understood. Please check the edits to make sure I haven't accidentally changed the meaning.

Comment: I think it is fairly obvious what is being asked here. The main question is, are there other organs - besides those listed - that can repair/regenerate? If there are why do those repair/regenerate while others do not.

Comment: Edited the question again. Thanks for the help Chris Stronks. I was not aware of the damage a liver undergoes and I wanted to ask why internal organs have regenerating capacity at all if they don't wear out. Seems Liver do wear out constantly.

Answer (score 2):

It is not really essential that all vital organs should have regenerative potential (for example brain).

The cellular composition of a tissue is a big factor in deciding if the organ/tissue will regenerate or not. Some cells divide while others do not; highly specialized and polarized cells like neurons do not divide perhaps because the act of division itself will compromise their function. That doesn't mean these tissues cannot regenerate; they would need stem cells that can differentiate into the type of cells that died.

So regeneration can happen via:

- Division of the tissue cells (skin healing, liver regeneration)
- Differentiation of stem cells (erythropoesis, muscle regeneration)

Organs that do not have non-dividing cells can regenerate by simply proliferating whereas others would need to maintain a stem cell niche- which is not possible in all tissues. Maintenance of stem cells also adds up to the cost of metabolism; so there is some tradeoff.